# cannot find WCF endpoint with name

Tags: c#, wcf

I have RESTFUL WCF with web.config looks like

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                <security mode="None" />
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig2" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                <security mode="None" />
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="secureBasicHttpBindingConfig" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                <security mode="Transport" />
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name ="servicebehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restbehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="Schools.WebService.SchoolsWebService" behaviorConfiguration ="servicebehavior">

        <endpoint name="SOAPEndPoint" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="Schools.WebService.ISchoolsWebService" address ="soap"/>
        <endpoint name="RESTEndPoint" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="Schools.WebService.ISchoolsWebService" address ="rest" behaviorConfiguration ="restbehavior"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />

        </service>
    </services>

</system.serviceModel>
```

but when create webrefrence  to use (SOAP) by

```
_tempClient = new ArabicEWorldWebServiceClient("SOAPEndPoint");
```

I got error :

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'SOAPEndPoint' and contract 'SchoolsWebServiceClientInstance.ISchoolsWebService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the client configuration or it might be wrong. You just posted your service config. On the client side you also need to configure an endpoint to be able to open channel to your service. Client endpoints are defined inside the `<client>` tag of the `<system.serviceModel>`

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details on client configuration.

Your client configuration could look somewhat like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
           <basicHttpBinding>
            <!--This is only an example. Make sure your binding configuration regarding security and other matters, matches your service.-->
            <binding name="httpBindingConfig" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint
            name="SOAPEndPoint"
            address="http://localhost/SOAP"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="httpBindingConfig"
            contract="Schools.WebService.ISchoolsWebService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I believe the configuration you posted is incorrect. `<basicHttpBinding>` is not a child element of `<client>`, it's a child element of `<bindings>`.

Comment: @Tim: Thx for your comment, I somehow misplaced it completly. It is now corrected.